# Compare code in reverse each word in sentence

Tags: c

I have school task. To reverse each word in sentence, so example :

Input: `Fried chicken, fried duck.`

Output: `deirF nekcihc, deirf kcud.`

So except dot and comma it's not reversed.

The first code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i, n, titik = 0, coma = 0;
    char s[5001];
    char c[5001];
    char *tok;
    scanf("%[^\n]s", s);
    if (s[0] == ' ')
        printf(" ");
    tok = strtok(s, " ");
    while (tok != NULL) {
        strcpy(c, tok);
        n = strlen(c);
        for (i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (c[i] == ',') {
                coma = 1;
            } else
            if (c[i] == '.') {
                titik = 1;
            } else 
                printf("%c", c[i]);
        }
        if (coma) {
            printf(",");
            coma = 0;
        } else
        if (titik){
            printf(".");
            titik = 0;
        }
        tok = strtok(NULL," ");
        if (tok == NULL)
            printf("\n");
        else
            printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Second code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, n, prana = 0, titik = 0, coma = 0, end = 0;
    char s[5001];
    scanf("%[^\n]s", s);
    n = strlen(s);

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (isspace(s[i]) || iscntrl(s[i])) {
            if (iscntrl(s[i]))
                end = 1;

            for (j = i - 1; j >= prana; j--) {
                if (s[j] == '.') {
                    titik = 1;
                } else
                if (s[j] == ',') {
                    coma = 1;
                } else
                    printf("%c", s[j]);
            }
            prana = i + 1;
            if (titik) {
                titik = 0;
                if (end)
                    printf(".");
                else
                    printf(". ");
            } else
            if (coma) {
                coma = 0;
                if (end)
                    printf(",");
                else
                    printf(", ");
            } else {
                if (end)
                    printf("");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Why the second code is accepted in test case?, but first code is not.
I tested the result it's same. Really identical in md5 hash.

Comment: Is it rejected by an automatic judging tool or by a person?

Comment: Is it rejected based on the output to a known test input (or set of input tets)? If yes, what is the test input?

Comment: Are supposed to use, or not use, certain methods, mechanisms, libs, constructs, ... ?

Comment: The first code isn't very general. It just checks for commas and stops after a word, ignores all other punctuation and relies on spaces between words. What if the test case is, for example, "What? Im.not sure..."? It's probably better (and simpler) to identify chunks of letters and reverse those.

Comment: The second code, in contrast to the accepted first code, gets a warning on usign a zero length format string in line 44 when being compiled with `gcc -Wall`. The first code "only" gets a warning on returning from main() without an explicit `return`. Maybe the first warning is considered "bad" the second not.

Comment: Well, the second code isn't very general,either. The md5sums aren't identical, by the way. The first code will print a null value before each reversed token. This is the terminating null character of the tokens. It doesn't show in the console, but it _is_ part of the output.

Comment: Yes, I suspect there are corner-cases where your code is failing where the second code does not. Identifying corner-cases can be difficult, but you should try to construct test cases with a `','` at the beginning/end, a test case with all `','` and `'.'` characters, sentences with two or more `'.'` together, e.g. `etc...`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the two codes id different, because you print the terminating null character for each token in the first code. This loop:

```
for (i = n; i >=0 ; i--) ...
```

will have `i == n` in its first iteration. For a C string of length `n`, s[n] is the terminating null. This character may not show in the console, but it is part of the output.

To fix the loop, you could start with `i = n - 1`, but C uses inclusive lower bounds and exclusive upper bounds, and a more idomatic loop syntax is:

```
i = n;
while (i-- > 0) ...
```

---

Not related to your question at hand, but your codes are rather complicated, because they rely on many assumptions: words separated by spaces; only punctuation is comma or stop; repeated punctuation marks are ignored, special case for last word.

Here's a solution that treats all chunks of alphabetic characters plus the apostrophe as words and reverses them in place:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void reverse(char *str, int i, int j)
{
    while (i < j) {
        int c = str[--j];

        str[j] = str[i];
        str[i++] = c;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[512];
    int begin = -1;
    int i;

    if (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) == NULL) return -1;

    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char) str[i]) || str[i] == '\'') {
            if (begin == -1)  begin = i;
        } else {
            if (begin != -1) {
                reverse(str, begin, i);
                begin = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```